# Asking for a grammar tense

Tags: grammar

There is something I don’t understand in between present perfect simple (PPS) and present perfect continuous (PPC).

As we know,

PPC = has/have + been + ing

PPS = has/have + ed

So why we use:

I have been married for 2 years

Not

I have been marrying for 2 years?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any difference between Present Perfect and Present Perfect Continuous?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66894/is-there-any-difference-between-present-perfect-and-present-perfect-continuous)

Comment: Both are grammatical. They just mean different things. And one of those things is extremely common, while the other thing is extremely rare. Because of that, one of the sentences is much more common than the other.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the form "be + adjective" and the closely related "be + past participle" (the passive voice).

So the verb "to marry" has two senses

1. Jon marries Mary.
2. The priest marries Jon and Mary.

These both relate to an act, not a state.

If I want to talk about the state I need the adjective "married" (which comes from the past participle or marry). There are two ways of using the adjective.

1. Jon is married to Mary
2. Jon and Mary are married.

If I want to use this in the "until now" sense, I need to use the present perfect:

> Jon has been married to Mary for 5 years.

Now, "has been marrying" is also correct grammar. Remember the priest?

> The priest has been marrying couples for 5 years.

It means that the priest has been performing ceremonies for 5 years.  (it could also mean one ceremony has lasted for 5 years, but that seems impossible, so I don't even consider that as a possible meaning)